# Get user latitude and longitude using myLocation from google map blackberry api

Tags: blackberry, gps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

Is it possible to extract users current latitude and longitude using google map api for blackberry? If so how?

Comment: What API are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

For newer Blackberry devices at least, you can do this with Google Maps JavaScript API v3.  See http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#DetectingUserLocation